# Item in listview is repeating

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have the following arrayadapter .

```
public class SmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    List<String> smsBody;
    List<Boolean> Status;
    List<String> time;
    List<String> SmsMessageId;

    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String fromNumber;

    public SmsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> smsBody,
            List<Boolean> Status, List<String> time, List<String> SmsMessageId,
            String fromNumber) {
        super(context, resource, smsBody);
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.fromNumber = fromNumber;
        this.time = time;
        this.SmsMessageId=SmsMessageId;
    }

    public String getStr(int position) {
        return smsBody.get(position);
    }
    public String getId(int position)
    {
        return SmsMessageId.get(position);
    }
    public void setRead(int position,String smsMessageId)
    {
        Status.set(position, true);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read", true);
        context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values, "_id=" +smsMessageId, null);
    }
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return smsBody.get(position);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textfrom;
        public TextView text_sms;
        public TextView text_time;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textfrom = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_from);
            holder.text_sms = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);
            holder.text_time = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_time);

            holder.textfrom.setText(" " + fromNumber);

            String smsTextToDisplay = smsBody.get(position);
            if (smsTextToDisplay.length() > 100)
                smsTextToDisplay = smsTextToDisplay.substring(0, 99) + " ...";

            holder.text_sms.setText(smsTextToDisplay);


            holder.text_time.setText(time.get(position));
            if (Status.get(position) == false) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.light_blue_overlay));

            }

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



        return convertView;
    }

}
```

In my customized list view items are repeating.position of item is same for all item. Where is the error ? How can I avoid this error ?

The code of set adapter is as follows :

```
arrayAdapter = new SmsArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, smsBody,
                status, time, SmsMessageId, fromNumber);
        smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: can you please provide your code of setadapter?

Comment: What is setadapter ?

Comment: arrayAdapter = new SmsArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, smsBody,
    status, time, SmsMessageId, fromNumber);
  smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
  smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Comment: where you have set your adapter in listview

Comment: try to logcat your all List<String> , so that you can check there is not repeating items in your list also

Answer (score 0):

The reason is **Views** in **Listview** are recycled upon scroll. Change your `getView()` like this:

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {

                /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

                /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.textfrom = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_from);
                holder.text_sms = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);
                holder.text_time = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_time);

/************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

                holder.textfrom.setText(" " + fromNumber);

                String smsTextToDisplay = smsBody.get(position);
                if (smsTextToDisplay.length() > 100)
                    smsTextToDisplay = smsTextToDisplay.substring(0, 99) + " ...";

                holder.text_sms.setText(smsTextToDisplay);


                holder.text_time.setText(time.get(position));
                if (Status.get(position) == false) {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.light_blue_overlay));

                } 

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: But when I change code like this , my code gets exception .

Comment: this wont work. You are not filling the views that are created. So the unrecycled views will be empty.

Comment: @DanielBo have you checked code below if/else statement? That is where views are populated with data

Comment: nvm, you didnt set the bracked i saw the closing one and assumed it was supposed to close the else block.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your implementation of the Viewholder is wrong. You are not setting the data onto the recycled views. You can completely remove the else block and just set your data.

```
 ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

        /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.textfrom = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_from);
        holder.text_sms = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);
        holder.text_time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_time);

        }

        /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.textfrom.setText(" " + fromNumber);
    String smsTextToDisplay = smsBody.get(position);
    if (smsTextToDisplay.length() > 100)
        smsTextToDisplay = smsTextToDisplay.substring(0, 99) + " ...";

    holder.text_sms.setText(smsTextToDisplay);


    holder.text_time.setText(time.get(position));
    if (Status.get(position) == false) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.light_blue_overlay));

    return convertView;
}
```

In addition I'd recommend using RecyclerView instead of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

It is very Common Problem in inflating, Just make sure that you should clear every condition in your adapter i.e for every **if** condition there should be meaningful **else** condition because your getView method will be called upon every scrolling to recycle views.

This is the approach I have implemented when I got same problem, Please ignore if this wouldn't help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textfrom = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_from);
            holder.text_sms = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);
            holder.text_time = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_time);

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
/////////////////////Added///////////////
            holder.textfrom.setText(" " + fromNumber);

            String smsTextToDisplay = smsBody.get(position);
            if (smsTextToDisplay.length() > 100)
                smsTextToDisplay = smsTextToDisplay.substring(0, 99) + " ...";

            holder.text_sms.setText(smsTextToDisplay);


            holder.text_time.setText(time.get(position));
            if (Status.get(position) == false) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.light_blue_overlay));

            }
////////Added//////////////

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Using this code , My activity gets stopped upon scrolling . What can I do ?

Comment: Are you getting any error? It must not be because of this re-ordering.

Comment: On scrolliong , I get exception for this re-ordering .

Comment: I have faced this issue.  And fixed with this ordering. Can you tell the expection?

Comment: @osimerpothe check whether all the list has equal number of size